# Hibernate HQL returning multiple values throws NullPointerException while parsing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a problem with an HQL query. I want to return multiple values in one single query (basically a tuple with an entity and a boolean value, whether something exists for that entity).

I am using JPA Repositories in Spring data JPA.

My query is:

```
@Query("select os, exists("
        + " select z from Zaznam z"
        + " inner join z.instanciaOkna io with (io.okno = :okno)"           
        + " where z.osoba = os)"
        + " from Osoba os where os in (:osoby)")
public List<Object[]> findPritomneOsoby(@Param("osoby") List<Osoba> osoby, @Param("okno") Okno okno);
```

When starting a Jetty server, Hibernate tries to parse this query and throws following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ParameterTranslationsImpl.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterTranslationsImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.buildParameterMetadata(HQLQueryPlan.java:316)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:124)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1784)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:91)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:66)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.fromQueryAnnotation(SimpleJpaQuery.java:169)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:160)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:290)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1454)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:787)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:434)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:779)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:284)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1322)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:731)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.restartWebApp(JettyRunMojo.java:521)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo$1.filesChanged(JettyRunMojo.java:475)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportBulkChanges(Scanner.java:681)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:539)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

My entity classes:
Osoba.java:

```
package sk.uniba.edo.EDOApp.model;


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

/**
 * Osoba generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "osoba", schema = "public")
public class Osoba implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3721133687065786579L;

    private long id;
    private Osoba osobaByUpravil;
    private Osoba osobaByVytvoril;
    private Osoba osobaByZmazal;
    private String meno;
    private String priezvisko;
    private String titulPred;
    private String titulZa;
    private String login;
    private String externeId;
    private String heslo;
    private boolean aktivny;
    private Date zmazany;
    private Set<PoziadavkaOkno> poziadavkaOknos = new HashSet<PoziadavkaOkno>(0);
    private Set<OsobaInstanciaBody> osobaInstanciaBodies = new HashSet<OsobaInstanciaBody>(0);
    private Set<OsobaRola> osobaRoly = new HashSet<OsobaRola>(0);
    private Set<Osoba> osobasForVytvoril = new HashSet<Osoba>(0);
    private Set<Osoba> osobasForZmazal = new HashSet<Osoba>(0);
    private Set<Preukaz> preukazs = new HashSet<Preukaz>(0);

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "upravil")
    public Osoba getOsobaByUpravil() {
        return this.osobaByUpravil;
    }

    public void setOsobaByUpravil(Osoba osobaByUpravil) {
        this.osobaByUpravil = osobaByUpravil;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vytvoril")
    public Osoba getOsobaByVytvoril() {
        return this.osobaByVytvoril;
    }

    public void setOsobaByVytvoril(Osoba osobaByVytvoril) {
        this.osobaByVytvoril = osobaByVytvoril;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "zmazal")
    public Osoba getOsobaByZmazal() {
        return this.osobaByZmazal;
    }

    public void setOsobaByZmazal(Osoba osobaByZmazal) {
        this.osobaByZmazal = osobaByZmazal;
    }

    @Column(name = "meno", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getMeno() {
        return this.meno;
    }

    public void setMeno(String meno) {
        this.meno = meno;
    }

    @Column(name = "priezvisko", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getPriezvisko() {
        return this.priezvisko;
    }

    public void setPriezvisko(String priezvisko) {
        this.priezvisko = priezvisko;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"titulPred\"", length = 50)
    public String getTitulPred() {
        return this.titulPred;
    }

    public void setTitulPred(String titulPred) {
        this.titulPred = titulPred;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"titulZa\"", length = 50)
    public String getTitulZa() {
        return this.titulZa;
    }

    public void setTitulZa(String titulZa) {
        this.titulZa = titulZa;
    }

    @Column(name = "login", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 15)
    public String getLogin() {
        return this.login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"externeID\"", nullable = false, length = 12)
    public String getExterneId() {
        return this.externeId;
    }

    public void setExterneId(String externeId) {
        this.externeId = externeId;
    }

    @Column(name = "heslo", length = 40)
    public String getHeslo() {
        return this.heslo;
    }

    public void setHeslo(String heslo) {
        this.heslo = heslo;
    }

    @Column(name = "aktivny", nullable = false)
    public boolean isAktivny() {
        return this.aktivny;
    }

    public void setAktivny(boolean aktivny) {
        this.aktivny = aktivny;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "zmazany", length = 22)
    public Date getZmazany() {
        return this.zmazany;
    }

    public void setZmazany(Date zmazany) {
        this.zmazany = zmazany;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "osoba")
    public Set<PoziadavkaOkno> getPoziadavkaOknos() {
        return this.poziadavkaOknos;
    }

    public void setPoziadavkaOknos(Set<PoziadavkaOkno> poziadavkaOknos) {
        this.poziadavkaOknos = poziadavkaOknos;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "osoba")
    public Set<OsobaInstanciaBody> getOsobaInstanciaBodies() {
        return this.osobaInstanciaBodies;
    }

    public void setOsobaInstanciaBodies(Set<OsobaInstanciaBody> osobaInstanciaBodies) {
        this.osobaInstanciaBodies = osobaInstanciaBodies;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "osoba")
    public Set<OsobaRola> getOsobaRoly() {
        return this.osobaRoly;
    }

    public void setOsobaRoly(Set<OsobaRola> osobaRoly) {
        this.osobaRoly = osobaRoly;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "osobaByVytvoril")
    public Set<Osoba> getOsobasForVytvoril() {
        return this.osobasForVytvoril;
    }

    public void setOsobasForVytvoril(Set<Osoba> osobasForVytvoril) {
        this.osobasForVytvoril = osobasForVytvoril;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "osobaByZmazal")
    public Set<Osoba> getOsobasForZmazal() {
        return this.osobasForZmazal;
    }

    public void setOsobasForZmazal(Set<Osoba> osobasForZmazal) {
        this.osobasForZmazal = osobasForZmazal;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "osoba")
    public Set<Preukaz> getPreukazs() {
        return this.preukazs;
    }

    public void setPreukazs(Set<Preukaz> preukazs) {
        this.preukazs = preukazs;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getPlneMeno() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        if ((titulPred != null) && (titulPred.trim().length() > 0)) {
            result.append(String.format("%s ", titulPred));
        }
        result.append(String.format("%s %s", meno, priezvisko));
        if ((titulZa != null) && (titulZa.trim().length() > 0)) {
            result.append(String.format(", %s", titulZa));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[Osoba %d: %s %s]", id, meno, priezvisko);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Osoba))
            return false;
        Osoba osoba = (Osoba) obj;
        return (id == osoba.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new Long(id).hashCode();
    }

}
```

Zaznam.java:

```
   package sk.uniba.edo.EDOApp.model;



import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Zaznam generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "zaznam", schema = "hodnotenie")
public class Zaznam implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private Osoba zaznamenalOsoba;
    private Osoba osoba;
    private InstanciaOkna instanciaOkna;
    private Terminal terminal;
    private Date casPrichodu;
    private Date casZaznamu;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "zaznamenal", nullable = false)
    public Osoba getZaznamenalOsoba() {
        return this.zaznamenalOsoba;
    }

    public void setZaznamenalOsoba(Osoba osobaByZaznamenal) {
        this.zaznamenalOsoba = osobaByZaznamenal;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "osoba", nullable = false)
    public Osoba getOsoba() {
        return this.osoba;
    }

    public void setOsoba(Osoba osobaByOsoba) {
        this.osoba = osobaByOsoba;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instancia_okna", nullable = false)
    public InstanciaOkna getInstanciaOkna() {
        return instanciaOkna;
    }

    public void setInstanciaOkna(InstanciaOkna instanciaOkna) {
        this.instanciaOkna = instanciaOkna;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "terminal", nullable = false)
    public Terminal getTerminal() {
        return this.terminal;
    }

    public void setTerminal(Terminal terminal) {
        this.terminal = terminal;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "cas_prichodu", nullable = false, length = 29)
    public Date getCasPrichodu() {
        return this.casPrichodu;
    }

    public void setCasPrichodu(Date casPrichodu) {
        this.casPrichodu = casPrichodu;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "cas_zaznamu", nullable = false, length = 29)
    public Date getCasZaznamu() {
        return this.casZaznamu;
    }

    public void setCasZaznamu(Date casZaznamu) {
        this.casZaznamu = casZaznamu;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[Zaznam %d: cas prichodu %s pre osobu %d]", id, casPrichodu, osoba.getId());
    }

}
```

InstanciaOkna.java:

```
package sk.uniba.edo.EDOApp.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "instancia_okna", schema = "rozvrh")
public class InstanciaOkna implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private Okno okno;
    private Date datumcasOd;
    private Date datumcasDo;
    private List<Zaznam> zaznamy;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "okno", nullable = false)
    public Okno getOkno() {
        return okno;
    }

    public void setOkno(Okno okno) {
        this.okno = okno;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "datumcas_od")
    public Date getDatumcasOd() {
        return datumcasOd;
    }

    public void setDatumcasOd(Date datumcas) {
        this.datumcasOd = datumcas;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "datumcas_do")
    public Date getDatumcasDo() {
        return datumcasDo;
    }

    public void setDatumcasDo(Date datumcasDo) {
        this.datumcasDo = datumcasDo;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instanciaOkna")
    public List<Zaznam> getZaznamy() {
        return zaznamy;
    }

    public void setZaznamy(List<Zaznam> zaznamy) {
        this.zaznamy = zaznamy;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[InstanciaOkna: ID=%d, od=%s, do=%s, okno=%s]", id, datumcasOd, datumcasDo, okno);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof InstanciaOkna))
            return false;
        InstanciaOkna io = (InstanciaOkna) obj;
        return (id == io.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new Long(id).hashCode();
    }

}
```

Okno.java:

```
package sk.uniba.edo.EDOApp.model;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

/**
 * Okno generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "okno", schema = "rozvrh")
public class Okno implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private TypOkno typOkno;
    private PredmetInstancia predmetInstancia;
    private Den den;
    private Date od;
    private Date do_;
    private Set<OsobaRola> instanciaRoly = new HashSet<OsobaRola>(0);
    private Set<PoziadavkaOkno> poziadavkaOknosForCielOkno = new HashSet<PoziadavkaOkno>(0);
    private Set<Volno> volnos = new HashSet<Volno>(0);
    private Set<PoziadavkaOkno> poziadavkaOknosForZdrojOkno = new HashSet<PoziadavkaOkno>(0);
    private List<InstanciaOkna> instancieOkna = new ArrayList<>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
    @JoinColumn(name = "typ_okno", nullable = false)
    public TypOkno getTypOkno() {
        return this.typOkno;
    }

    public void setTypOkno(TypOkno typOkno) {
        this.typOkno = typOkno;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instancia", nullable = false)
    public PredmetInstancia getPredmetInstancia() {
        return this.predmetInstancia;
    }

    public void setPredmetInstancia(PredmetInstancia predmetInstancia) {
        this.predmetInstancia = predmetInstancia;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "den", nullable = false)
    public Den getDen() {
        return this.den;
    }

    public void setDen(Den den) {
        this.den = den;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name = "od", nullable = false, length = 15)
    public Date getOd() {
        return this.od;
    }

    public void setOd(Date od) {
        this.od = od;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name = "do", nullable = false, length = 15)
    public Date getDo_() {
        return this.do_;
    }

    public void setDo_(Date do_) {
        this.do_ = do_;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "okno")
    public Set<OsobaRola> getInstanciaRoly() {
        return this.instanciaRoly;
    }

    public void setInstanciaRoly(Set<OsobaRola> instanciaRolas) {
        this.instanciaRoly = instanciaRolas;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "oknoByCielOkno")
    public Set<PoziadavkaOkno> getPoziadavkaOknosForCielOkno() {
        return this.poziadavkaOknosForCielOkno;
    }

    public void setPoziadavkaOknosForCielOkno(Set<PoziadavkaOkno> poziadavkaOknosForCielOkno) {
        this.poziadavkaOknosForCielOkno = poziadavkaOknosForCielOkno;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "okno")
    public Set<Volno> getVolnos() {
        return this.volnos;
    }

    public void setVolnos(Set<Volno> volnos) {
        this.volnos = volnos;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "oknoByZdrojOkno")
    public Set<PoziadavkaOkno> getPoziadavkaOknosForZdrojOkno() {
        return this.poziadavkaOknosForZdrojOkno;
    }

    public void setPoziadavkaOknosForZdrojOkno(Set<PoziadavkaOkno> poziadavkaOknosForZdrojOkno) {
        this.poziadavkaOknosForZdrojOkno = poziadavkaOknosForZdrojOkno;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "okno")
    public List<InstanciaOkna> getInstancieOkna() {
        return instancieOkna;
    }

    public void setInstancieOkna(List<InstanciaOkna> instancieOkna) {
        this.instancieOkna = instancieOkna;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {      
        return String.format("%s od %s do %s", den.getNazov(), od, do_);                
    }

}
```

What is the problem with this query?

Comment: move with (io.okno = :okno) in where condition of subquery. Instead return z you can return 'DUMMYTEXT' because is the output of an EXISTS function. Tell me if it's OK

Comment: Still getting NPE...


java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ParameterTranslationsImpl.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterTranslationsImpl.java:87)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.buildParameterMetadata(HQLQueryPlan.java:316)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:124)
...

My new query:
@Query("select os, exists("
   + " select z from Zaznam z"
   + " inner join z.instanciaOkna io"   
   + " where z.osoba = os and io.okno = :okno)"
   + " from Osoba os where os = :osoby")